# Small baskets for fries

Tags: french-fries, serving

Are small baskets for french fries actually used to cook them or just to serve?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They just look like gimmick frying basket used for serving.

When you fry things, you need to have "space" in the fryer to have a good consistent frying so that you have as much surface of the ingredients touch the hot oil as possible.

If the ingredients get clustered together, they will stick and probably not cook evenly.